# Writing specs in flow: test whether variables got set

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, flowtype

I have the following spec, where `somePromise()` returns true or throws an error:

```
describe('context level 1', () => {
  let a;
  let error;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    a = undefined;
    error = undefined;

    try {
      a = await somePromise();
    } catch (e) {
      error = e;
    }
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    a = null;
    error = null;
  });


  describe('context level 2', () => {
    before(() => {
      doSomeSetup();
    });

    it('test case 1', () => {
      a.should.balahalah();
    });
  });

  describe('context level 2', () => {
    before(() => {
      doSomeSetup();
    });

    it('test case 2', () => {
      error.message.should.equal('xxxdasfsda');
    });
  });
});
```

Specs work as expected, but `flow check` (my project uses facebook flow) shows errors such as:

> Cannot get error.message because property message is missing in null
>   [1].

Question: how should these specs be written in flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly deal with all possible scenarios to avoid the flow error.

```js
describe('context level 1', () => {
  describe('context level 2', () => {
    before(() => {
      doSomeSetup();
    });

    it('test case 1', () => {
      try {
        const a = await subject();
        should(result).balahalah();
      } catch (e) {
        should.not.exist(e);
      }
    });
  });

  describe('context level 2', () => {
    before(() => {
      doSomeSetup();
    });

    it('test case 2', () => {
      try {
        const a = await subject();
        should.not.exist(a);
      } catch (e) {
        e.message.should.equal('xxxdasfsda');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Flow doesn't know about things like `beforeEach`, nor should it. Flow is saying that it's possible that `error` could be `null` in your test. In your case, your test runner should catch the exception and fail the test if this is the case. So there are two ways to handle this:

### 1) Let the test runner handle exceptions

You can modify `.flowconfig` to include this:

```
[options]
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$ExpectError
```

Then in your test:

```
// $ExpectError
error.message.should.equal('xxxdasfsda');
```

This means you know there's a flow error here, but it will be handled by the test runner if it occurs.

### 2) Rely on Flow

I prefer this method, even though it results in more code, because it's more explicit and the test is clearer:

```
it('test case 2', () => {
  if (!error) {
    assert.fail('Error was not set correctly');
  }
  error.message.should.equal('xxxdasfsda');
});
```